# Less hyphenations - any value to change?

Tags: hyphenation

I don't want to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating - unfortunately I write in a language, which consists of rather long words. That results in quite a lot of hyphenations, not to mention that I have to deal with plenty of them manually. Albeit I use babel package.

My guess is LaTeX operates with a certain value, which says how many percent of line can be blank/without characters. It probably takes into consideration all lines in the paragraph or on the page. Am I correct? Any way to change such parameter?

Or should I rather make the text block wider? That could help?

Comment: The relevant TeX parameters are `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`. For English language documents, these are usually set to 2 and 3, respectively; hyphenation point won't occur before the second character or after the third-to-last character of a word. For German language documents, these parameters are usually set to 2 and 2, respectively. Which language do you write in? Do you use the `babel` and/or `polyglossia` packages? They provide not only generic language-specific settings but also provide language-appropriate hyphenation exception patterns.

Comment: I do use relevant babel (Czech), which does hyphenate most of words correctly. Yet, it doesn't hyphenate all of them. I mean, the results themselves are not that bad - I just want to play with settings a little bit and see the differences.

Comment: The TeX/LaTeX hyphenation algorithm operates on one paragraph at a time. To be more restrictive about permissible hyphenation, e.g., to  have only longer words hyphenated, and even then only in the "middle" of the words, you could experiment with `\renewcommand\czechhyphenmins{44}`. To be more permissive about hyphenation, you could issue the instruction `\renewcommand\czechhyphenmins{22}`. (Be forewarned that being "permissive" in this sense may induce LaTeX to identify hyphenation points that aren't appropriate.)

Comment: If you aren’t loading `microtype`, adding it will help.

Comment: If the language has long words, hyphenation is necessary: you get *worse* results if you make it less desirable for TeX to hyphenate.

Comment: @egreg: Well, depends. If it's starting to get ridiculous (like in Finnish many times), like getting hyphens for *every single line*, then I think it's better to have more space between words to try and avoid *that much* hyphenation.

Comment: @morbusg Really? I looked at an edition of [Seitsemän veljestä](http://goo.gl/ZFbQ1V) and there are many hyphens.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't mean "no hyphens at all", rather, striking a balance between them when there starts to be too many of them. But cool you found Seitsemän veljestä `:-)`, though the language in it is a bit archaic and perhaps not so representative of the long-words-language point.

Comment: @morbusg Of course I can't understand a word out of it. `;-)` If you increase `\hyphenpenalty` you also need to increase `\tolerance`, so wider interword spaces are accepted by TeX.

Answer (score 4):

There are some demerits related to hyphenation in TeX, such as:

- `\doublehyphendemerits`, added for two consecutive lines ending with discretionary break, and
- `\finalhyphendemerits` added for second-last line of paragraph

where demerits are in units of "badness squared". And for actual badness, there is

- `\hyphenpenalty` for line break after discretionary hyphen,
- `\exhyphenpenalty` for line break after explicit hyphen, and
- `\brokenpenalty` for page break after a hyphenated line.

These are in addition to the ones mentioned in the comments (`\left`- and `\righthyphenmin`).

The obvious choice would therefore be upping the `\hyphenpenalty` (I think it's 50 by default).